# What are non-pure functions in Python?

Tags: python

As a definition, I learnt that,

> non-pure functions have some input (their arguments) and return some output (the result of applying them) *[...]* and in addition *[...]* can also generate side effects, *which make some change to the state of interpreter or computer*.

(Paraphrased from *[Building Abstractions with Functions (PDF)](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/sp12/book/functions.pdf)*.)

For example: the `print(2)` function returns nothing (`None`) in addition as a side effect print function (not Python interpreter) itself prints the value.

In the above definition, I did not understand the meaning of 'changing the state of interpreter or computer'. What does that mean?

Comment: this definition has been taken from http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/sp12/book/functions.pdf

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Any function that affects any state other than that of local variables is a non-pure function.

Changing a global is non-pure, for example:

```
some_list = []

def foo(bar):
    some_list.append(bar)

foo('baz')
```

The function `foo` changed the state of `some_list`; it is thus non-pure. A pure version would be:

```
def foo(bar, lst):
    return lst + [bar]

some_list = []
now_list = foo('baz', some_list)
```

Here `foo` only affects state by taking the input arguments and producing an output value. The original `some_list` object was not mutated either, a new object was returned instead.

Pure functions also must produce outputs that depend *only* on the inputs; a function that produces input based on external state is not pure either. `time.time()` is not pure, it returns a value based on the state of a clock, which was not an input to the function.

Comment: kind of imperative programming?

Comment: it should also always map same arguments to the same results; for example `time.time()` is impure, even though it does not change any state

Comment: Can we call this non-pure function as imperative programming?

Comment: @Sham: Not necessarily. Imperative programming is non-pure, but that doesn't mean that all non-pure code is imperative.

Comment: @Sham: The core of SQL is not imperative, it is, at its heart, a declarative language, but you wouldn't say it is pure, because you are mutating state.

Answer (score 5):

We call a function pure if it satisfies two important extra properties:

1. Behaviour that is only influence by input.

   - Most usually fails if the function code relies on a variable in the main namespace that was not passed in as an argument (making it local).
2. Influence on the rest of the program should only be via its output (return value).